# Visa thru a lawyer

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, tourist-visas, applications

I was refused UK tourist visa twice. Than I applied the visa thru a lawyer and it was accepted. It was a tourist visa and I been to UK twice. I like to travel again this summer; should the lawyer fill my application again and apply for me? Or  should I fill the application exactly like the way my  lawyer did it last time and attached all the documents and cover letter like he did last time? Some of the documents were not even required.

Comment: Have your circumstances changed significantly (finances, ties to home etc) changed since your successful application? Do you feel confident about filling in the application and supplying all the relevant documents? There’s no reason why you shouldn’t complete the application yourself without the aid of a lawyer, since you seem to understand how he went about it.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to answer this objectively. If you feel confident, do it yourself. If not, get your lawyer to do it. Only you can decide.